# Receiving 406 (Not acceptable) for AJAX action Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm trying to auto-refresh a single partial view every 60 seconds on the index page. I tried splitting the actions into two routes, so that the JS would be easier to change and manage. It seems to be a problem with the respond_to block, maybe you can help me with a better approach.

feed_controller.rb

```
def index
 @hashtags = hashtag_refresh
end

def hashtag_refresh
 Hashtag.order('created_at DESC').limit(10).uniq
 respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
end
```

feed\hashtag_refresh.js.erb

```
 $('.trends_li_container').html("<%= escape_javascript(render('feed/shared/hashtag_list')).html_safe %>");
```

routes.rb

```
get 'feed/hashtag_refresh', to: 'feed#hashtag_refresh'
```

hashtag_autorefresh.js

```
//Refresh Hashtags Partial
$(document).ready(function (){
    setTimeout(refreshHashtag, 60000)
});

//Calls action refreshing the partial
function refreshHashtag() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'feed/hashtag_refresh',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'script'
    })
}
```

feed/shared/ folder
_hashtag_list.html.erb

feed/ controller folder
hashtag_refresh.js.erb

Server Development Log

```
  Started GET "/feed/hashtag_refresh?_=1462210930323" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-05-02 13:45:05 -0400
    Processing by FeedController#hashtag_refresh as JS
      Parameters: {"_"=>"1462210930323"}
      User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
      Rendered feed/shared/_hashtag_list.html.erb (0.0ms)
      Rendered feed/hashtag_refresh.js.erb (11.5ms)
    Completed 200 OK in 50ms (Views: 47.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Thank you all for helping me. It seems to be working now. I made a few changes to the code as shown above. I combined both of your ideas and I didn't need the respond_to block.

Answer (score 0):

try changing your function `refreshHashtag()` to this

```
//Calls action refreshing the partial
function refreshHashtag() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'feed/hashtag_refresh'
        type: 'GET', //POST
        dataType: 'script'
    })
}
```

Comment: What about the issue with the respond_to block? Or does that remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the returning value of `hashtag_refresh`. You expect it to return a collection of `Hashtag`s, but actually it returns the return value of `respond_to`, which I don't know what it really is :P

Try modifying your controller like this:

```
def index
  hashtag_refresh do |hashtags|
    @hashtags = hashtags
  end
end

def hashtag_refresh
  yield Hashtag.order('created_at DESC').limit(10).uniq
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

And your javascript

```
// Refresh Hashtags Partial
$(document).ready(function (){
  setInterval(refreshHashtag, 60000)
});


// Calls action refreshing the partial
function refreshHashtag() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'feed/hashtag_refresh.js',
    dataType: 'javascript'
  })
}
```

By the way, calling `setTimeout` recursively is preferred over `setInterval` because `setInterval` requires manual cancel, and if you forget to cancel, it will run forever. So your javascript can be like this:

```
//Refresh Hashtags Partial
$(document).ready(function (){
  (function refreshHashtag() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'feed/hashtag_refresh.js',
      dataType: 'javascript'
    }).then(function() {
      setTimeout(refreshHashtag, 60000);
    });
  })();
});
```

Hope it will resolve your problem :)

### UPDATE

If you got the error `ActionController::UnknownFormat`, then it simply means that rails don't recognize the format `js` or the mime type `text/javascript`. We can *teach* rails by adding some config in `config/initializers/mime_types.rb`

**config/initializers/mime_types.rb**

```
# The RFC standard mime type for javascript
Mime::Type.register "application/javascript", :js

# The legacy but widely used mime types for javascript
Mime::Type.register "text/javascript", :js
Mime::Type.register "application/x-javascript", :js
```

Comment: Sorry, my fault. The code of the controller is modified and this time it should not raise that error.

Comment: the respond_to block is still giving off errors: ActionController::UnknownFormat